# yf.Tickers from yfinance to download information for multiple tickers and dynamically access each of them

Tags: python, yfinance

My question is how to dynamically access each ticker when using yf.Tickers from yfinance in Python?

For example, I have a list of tickers: ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMD'] and use the following code to download thru yfinance:

```
import yfinance as yf
tickers = yf.Tickers('AAPL MSFT AMD')
tickers.AAPL.info
div = tickers.AAPL.info['trailingAnnualDividendYield']
```

Now I have to type in each ticker like this: `tickers.AAPL.info`. Does anyone know how I can access each ticker dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import yfinance as yf

stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMD']

for stock in stocks:
    info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
    div = info.get('trailingAnnualDividendYield')
    print(stock, div)
```

The output is:

```
AAPL 0.013894105
MSFT 0.013502605
AMD None
```

Comment: FYI yfinance.download(tickers, time_frame="1Y")

Answer (score 0):

According to [yfinance docs](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance):

Fetching data for multiple tickers:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("SPY AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = yf.Tickers('AAPL,MSFT,AMD')

for tick in tickers.tickers:
    if tick.info['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
        print(tick.info)
```